# How to compare two rows of two pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two python pandas series `df10` and `df5`. I want to compare their values.For example: `df10[-1:]< df5[-1:]` ,it returns true. `df10[-2:-1] > df5[-2:-1]` , it returns false.

But if I combine them together, `df10[-1:]< df5[-1:] and df10[-2:-1]>df5[-2:-1]`,it returns

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

But I expect it returns false. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "df10[-1:]< df5[-1:],it returns true".  Can you show an actual example with actual values illustrating what you expect the result to be?

Comment: @Jiaqi,  Use bitwise `AND` operator and enclose it within brackets, like so `(df10[-1:]< df5[-1:]) & (df10[-2:-1]> df5[-2:-1])` and the result you obtain must be `False`(logical `AND` of `True` and `False`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the pandas Series `values` attribute:

```
if (df10.values[-2:-1] > df5.values[-2:-1]) and\ 
        (df10.values[-1:] < df5.values[-1:]):
    print("we met the conditions!")
```

Answer (score 12):

Consider you have the two dataframes from this program:

```
# Python 3.5.2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# column names for example  dataframe
cats = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

df5 = pd.DataFrame(data = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), columns=cats)
print("Dataframe 5\n",df5,"\n")

df10=pd.DataFrame(data = np.transpose(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)), columns=cats)
print("Dataframe 10\n",df10)
```

The resulting data frames are:

```
Dataframe 5
     A   B   C   D   E
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24 

Dataframe 10
    A  B   C   D   E
0  0  5  10  15  20
1  1  6  11  16  21
2  2  7  12  17  22
3  3  8  13  18  23
4  4  9  14  19  24
```

Now let's look at the result of your first comparison:

```
print(df5[-1:])
print(df10[-1:])

a=df10[-1:]< df5[-1:]

print("\n",a,"\n",type(a))
```

which results in:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
4  20  21  22  23  24
   A  B   C   D   E
4  4  9  14  19  24

       A     B     C     D      E
4  True  True  True  True  False 
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Now the second comparison:

```
print(df5[-2:-1])
print(df10[-2:-1])

b=df10[-2:-1]>df5[-2:-1]
print("\n",b,"\n",type(b))
```

which has results:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
3  15  16  17  18  19
   A  B   C   D   E
3  3  8  13  18  23

        A      B      C      D     E
3  False  False  False  False  True 
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

**The issue:**

If we evaluate:

```
pd.Series([True, True, False, False]) and pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
```

What is the correct answer?:

1. `pd.Series([False, True, False, False])`
2. `False`
3. `True`
4. All of the above
5. Any of the above
6. It depends

The answer is: 6 - It depends. It depends on *what you want.*

First, we have to create boolean series for the comparison:

```
a_new = (df10[-1:] < df5[-1:]).any()
print(a_new,"\n",type(a_new))

b_new = (df10[-2:-1] > df5[-2:-1]).any()
print("\n",b_new,"\n",type(b_new))
```

The results are:

```
A     True
B     True
C     True
D     True
E    False
dtype: bool 
 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

A    False
B    False
C    False
D    False
E     True
dtype: bool 
 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Now, we can compute 3 cases.

**Case 1: a.any() and b.any()**

```
a.any() = True if any item in a is True
b.any() = True if any item in b is True
print(a_new.any() and b_new.any())
```

The result is **True.**

**Case 2: a.all() and b.all()**

```
a.all() = True if every item in a is True   
b.all() = True if every item in b is True
print(a_new.all() and b_new.all())
```

The result is **False.**

**Case 3: Pairwise comparison**

For this, you have to compare every element to each other.

```
result_pairwise = [a_new and b_new for a_new, b_new in zip(a_new,b_new)]
print(result_pairwise,"\n",type(result_pairwise))
```

The result is:

```
[False, False, False, False, False] 
 <class 'list'>
```

For more details:

- [Pandas Gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#gotchas-truth/%22Pandas%20Gotchas%22)
- [Boolean Reductions.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-compare)